# upload to S3 via CF distribution

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I need to have some zero code solution to upload files to s3 bucket. Say, no custom code allowed to be run on the client side and users have to explicitly approve such uploads.
I have an S3 bucket which is opened to public where I can upload some files using the following html at `https://x-x-x.s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/index.html`:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <form action="/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Key to upload:
    <input type="input"  name="key" value="${filename}" /><br />
    <!--input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read"/-->
    <input type="input"  name="Content-Type" value="text/plain" /><br />
    <input type="file"   name="file" /> <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload to Amazon S3" />
  </form>
</html>
```

Everything works fine. However, I need to create a CF distribution for this storage.
I enabled all verbs, http+https. The page `https://x-x-x.cloudfront.net/index.html` opens. But the submit of the upload button responds with MethodNotAllowed which puzzles me a lot.
Is there a way to fix the distribution to handle all uploads?

Comment: Enable S3 Transfer Acceleration and use it's endpoint to upload file. You can't upload through CloudFront as far as I'm aware.

Comment: The CF does not allow using accellerated endpoints

Comment: Yeah but you won't be using it in CF. Forget about CF for uploading files, just upload to the accelerate endpoint and use the CF endpoint to download content.